# Setting a field as index only if it is not empty

Tags: database, mongodb, go, indexing, mongo-go

I have a a structure with two keys as follows:

```json
{
    "cannot_be_empty": "hello",
    "can_be_empty": "world"
}
```

Right now I set the index to be a combination of `can_be_empty` and `cannot_be_empty`.

```golang
db.collection.Indexes.CreateOne(IndexModel{{Keys: bson.D{
    {Key: "cannot_be_empty", Value: 1}, 
    {Key: "can_be_empty", Value: 1},
}})
```

However, I want to make it such that `can_be_empty` must be unique across all fields unless it is an empty string. Is there a way to do this? I think https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/ might be the way to go, but I'm not too sure how it works in go.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I've found out that `$ne` does not work, so I tried this and presently my tests are still failing, but I'll try to find out why.

```golang
// Set partial index option
myPartialIndex := options.Index().SetPartialFilterExpression(bson.D{{
    Key:   "can_be_empty",
    Value: bson.D{{Key: "$gt", Value: ""}},
}})
// Set up all indexes
indexes := []mongo.IndexModel{
    {Keys: bson.D{{Key: "cannot_be_empty", Value: 1}, {Key: "can_be_empty", Value: 1}}},
    {Keys: bson.D{{Key: "can_be_empty", Value: 1}}, Options: myPartialIndex},
}
// Create index, no error
db.collection.Indexes().CreateMany(ctx, indexes)
```

UPDATE 2: I didn't know I had to add a unique option for this to work. In any case, I also need the compound key of `can_be_empty` and `cannot_be_empty` to be unique.

**FINAL UPDATE: I've accepted the answer, but will also post my own Golang version.**

```golang
myUniqueIndex := options.Index().SetUnique(true)
myPartialIndex := options.Index().SetPartialFilterExpression(bson.D{{
    Key:   "can_be_empty",
    Value: bson.D{{Key: "$gt", Value: ""}},
}})
// Set up all indexes
indexes := []mongo.IndexModel{
    {Keys: bson.D{{Key: "cannot_be_empty", Value: 1}, {Key: "can_be_empty", Value: 1}}, Options: myUniqueIndex},
    {Keys: bson.D{{Key: "can_be_empty", Value: 1}}, Options: myPartialIndex},
}
// Create index, no error
db.collection.Indexes().CreateMany(ctx, indexes)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `$gt` empty string.

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   { can_be_empty: 1, cannot_be_empty: 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "can_be_empty": {  "$gt": "" }  } }
)
```

Comment: Actually I tried this, but my unit test is failing when I check for error in duplicate insertion. I'm going to try debugging to see if it's another issue I'm facing.

Comment: Okay @absolutelydevastated This will work well if `can_be_empty` is a string type.

Comment: Yeah, I think I was missing the unique constraint. What if a combination of `can_be_empty` and `cannot_be_empty` must also be unique, regardless if they are empty or not?

Comment: @absolutelydevastated `unique: true` added in the index makes the combination to  be unique, but where `can_be_empty` is not an empty string.